# Mysql 5.7 equivalent to Mongos $elemMatch

Tags: mysql

Is there a way of querying an array of objects in MySQL 5.7 JSON datatype that is the equivalent of Mongos $elemMatch?

For example, if I had the following document saved in a MySQL JSON column

```
{
  fields: [
    {
      key: 'age',
      value: 20
    },
    {
      key: 'years_employed',
      value: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

In Mongo, I could use

```
.find({fields: {$elemMatch: {key:'age', value:20}}})
```

This would return any documents that contain a fields array containing an object having parameters that match both key and value. The above would return the example document, however the following would return nothing:

```
.find({fields: {$elemMatch: {key:'age', value:10}}})
```

I'm looking to find the same functionality in MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following JSON snippet in a JSON column named `data` in a table named `data_table`,

```
{
  fields: [
    {
      key: 'age',
      value: 20
    },
    {
      key: 'years_employed',
      value: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

you would use the [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) function, like in the following SQL statement, to select rows that match a specific 'age'

```
SELECT * FROM `data_table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`data`, '{"key":"age","value":20}', "$.fields")
```

I tested this on MySQL 5.7.17